# What input should I put in method call in blue j?

Tags: java, bluej

This is for the assignmet for the course *Principle of Software Design* on Coursera. When I try to run the `void sortbylargestdepth` method, I am prompted to put some input in the function call method. What input should I put there to run the method? Is this what suppose to happen or did I make a mistake in writing code? Below I have included the code as well as the screenshot of the problem: Hope to get a reply soon.

Here is the code for the method:

```
public void sortByLargestDepth(ArrayList<QuakeEntry> in) {    
    for (int i=0; i< 50; i++) {    
        int minIdx = getLargestDepth(in,i);    
        QuakeEntry qi = in.get(i);    
        QuakeEntry qmin = in.get(minIdx);    
        in.set(i,qmin);    
        in.set(minIdx,qi);   
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The method should have the signature changed to:

`public void sortByLargestDepth(ArrayList<QuakeEntry> quakeEntries)`

As the method is expecting an `ArrayList<QuakeEntry` (list of QuakeEntry's)
So you need to create a list and pass it in to the method call if one is not already provided.

Because we don't have the code for `QuakeEntry`, I will assume there is a default no-arg constructor. It would look something like:

```
ArrayList<QuakeEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
QuakeEntry entry1 = new QuakeEntry();
//Init entry 1 here
QuakeEntry entry2 = new QuakeEntry();
//Init entry 2 here (or better yet have a constructor that allows you to init
sortByLargestDepth(entries);
```

Comment: hi still it didn't work as expected..here is the link to my code: https://github.com/murat-aka/POSD/blob/gh-pages/week2/EarthquakeSortStarterProgram/QuakeSortInPlace.java

can you please look at the code and tell me what is wrong in it or modify? I am a beginner in Java so please cope with me if i asked silly question

Comment: Please post enough relevant code here for us to view and help. This also provides helpful information for others in the future.

Comment: this is the link to the whole code: https://github.com/murat-aka/POSD/blob/gh-pages/week2/EarthquakeSortStarterProgram/QuakeSortInPlace.java   

the problem is whenever i try to run any method of this class, it asks for some input which i have no idea what to put in. The code i wrote in the question above is the method for finding largest earthquake, but when i run the method, it asks for some input..may be you can try running the program in blue j?

Comment: But the relevant code related to your problem is not the class, but is the code where you are using the class,a main method? You need to show the code that calls the method and the actual errors given.